# How to display records for only 3 days

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

I used this query :

```
 function get_latest_news()
  {

    $sql = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM ArkibBerita
            WHERE code='BERITA' AND Enable = 'Y' AND Lang = 'EN'
            ORDER BY position ASC"; 

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
  }
```

For each record will only display 3 days. May I know how to query out a data which only display 3 days.

Thank you, niena

Comment: Please post sample data and expected result.

Comment: there is BeritaDate column in ArkibBerita. BeritaDate is a start date of the news will be display. I want the news only display for 3 days from the BeritaDate.

Comment: you have any date fiedl??

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM ArkibBerita
        WHERE code='BERITA' AND Enable = 'Y' AND Lang = 'EN'
        AND BeritaDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY // <--- this line
        ORDER BY position ASC"; 

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->result();
```

Comment: I think this will produce all records of beritadate greater than current dates  3 days before date.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM ArkibBerita
WHERE code='BERITA' AND Enable = 'Y' AND Lang = 'EN'
AND BeritaDate >= curdate( )
AND BeritaDate <= curdate( ) + INTERVAL 3 DAY
ORDER BY position ASC
```

OR

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM ArkibBerita
WHERE code='BERITA' AND Enable = 'Y' AND Lang = 'EN'
AND BeritaDate BETWEEN curdate( )
AND curdate( ) + INTERVAL 3 DAY
ORDER BY position ASC
```